# Why I am not getting 84.0? Whats wrong in the programming ?You must use recursion for this function

Tags: python, ipython

Here is my code:

```
def multiplyNums(list1):

    result = 1

    for element in list1:
        #print(element)
        if (type(element) == "int" or type(element) == "float"):
            print(result)
            result = result * element
            print("First loop", result)
        if (type(element) == "list"):
            for j in element:
                if (type(j) == "int" or type(j) == "float"):
                    result = result * j
                    print("Second loop", result)

    return result

a = ['Gon', 1, 'Killua', 7, [1,2, [2.0,'HxH'], 3]]
print(multiplyNums(a))
```

Comment: I spent a lot of time figuring out the problem, but I don't seem to get right answer. I don't know why. I pasted the example at the bottom. You must use recursion for this function.
Example:
>>> a = [‘Gon’, 1, ‘Killua’, 7, [1,2, [2.0,’HxH’], 3]]
>>> b = multiplyNums(a)
>>> print(b)
84.0

Comment: That looks like it will just resolve to `7*2*2*3`, which **is** 84. What else should you expect?

Comment: Why are you comparing types to strings?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: 84 is what he expects, but it doesn't get there.  The reason is that he tests a type's equality with a string.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type(element)` will never be `"int"` or `"float"`, etc.  It will be `int`, `float`, etc.  There is a built-in function, however, to check that called `isinstance`.  It takes as its first argument the element you are checking, and the second argument can be a type or a list of types.  Also, you aren't using recursion.  Here is the updated code:

```
def multiplyNums(list1):

    result = 1


    for element in list1:
        #print(element)
        if isinstance(element, (int, float)):
            print(result)
            result *= element
            print("First loop", result)
        elif isinstance(element, list):
            result *= multiplyNums(element)
    return result

a = ['Gon', 1, 'Killua', 7, [1,2, [2.0,'HxH'], 3]]
print(multiplyNums(a))
```

Notice the changes from `if type(...) == ...` to `if isinstance(..., ...)`.  Also in the `elif isinstance(element, list):` block, I used recursion instead of your solution that didn't take nested lists into account.  Also, `x *= y` is a shortcut for `x = x * y`.